# How to configure jenkins to run my robot script using jython interpreter instead of python?

Tags: jenkins, robotframework

I have created a Robot project and the test cases in the project are using keywords from a java class. So, I have to use jython interpreter to run my script. I did this in local via eclipse (Window -> Preferences -> Robot Framework -> Installed frameworks ). But, how to achieve the same in jenkins. Can any one please help me?

Answer (score 0):

When you're running the Eclipse version I'm going to assume that you're running RED. In this case the command that is executed to run your robot script is in the console pane which is similar to this:

[image]

The first line of this will typically start with something similar to this:

```
Command: C:\Python\Scripts\python.exe -m robot.run ....
```

This is the command that RED executes. In this command there is one part that should be removed, as it is used to feedback information from Robot Framework back to Eclipse/RED and is not needed for regular running.

```
--listener C:\Users\...\TestRunnerAgent.py:51909
```

As for the argument file, this can be changed as well though the [preferences](http://nokia.github.io/RED/help/user_guide/launching/launch_prefs.html).

In the Robot Framework Guide there is a specific section on how to execute test cases using [Robot Framework Command line interface](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#executing-test-cases).

Comment: Is that the only way to execute? Becasue, the command to execute my script goes to 3 to 4 lines since I have 4 jar files in class path.

Comment: That is the command line that RED generates based on the RED.xml and Run settings. These may not be optimal and can often be shortened by setting the correct CLASSPATH to the folder of your jar files by using relative paths instead of full ones. It should also be possible to import the jar file from Robot Script by using `Library   ./libs/name.jar`

Comment: Though I have used relative path in my classpath, the execution command populated by RED has absolute path only. But, I will try another way that  is mentioning jar details in script itself.